# Can't connect to Windows Server 2012 on Amazon EC2 through FTP over internet

Tags: ftp, firewall, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows Server 2012 on Amazon EC2, with IIS FTP set up and working (through local IP address of the machine within EC2). However I cannot connect to it over internet. In firewall I have ports 20-22 open for inbound connections and I have these same settings in EC2 instance's security group.

When I try to connect to it through FTP I receive this message:

> Server said: Server cannot accept argument. Error -162: PORT failed

When I tried to connect to it on the machine's Internet Explorer with local IP, it was working perfectly, but even there if I try to connect to it using public IP I'm not getting any response, only: "This page cannot be displayed"

I was using this tutorial for setting up FTP http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJBlyvLtTfs
and tried lot of Googling to solve this problem with no success.

Did I forget something?

I will appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Passive FTP [uses ports beyond 20 and 21](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html) (22 is ssh, which is unrelated, unless you mean SFTP).  Specifically, for each transfer you start, an ephemeral port will be allocated to transfer the data.

You will need to allow access to whatever [range the ephemeral ports are configured to use](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd463996%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).